# Why is Daredevil holding webs?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers, spider-man, avengers-vs-x-men

In one of the final panels to AvX #1 we see Spider-Man standing on the S.H.I.E.L.D helicarrier with his webbing in hand in a net-like shape, ready to strike.

Beside him we also see Daredevil holding similar net-like webbing. Is this something Spider-Man has given him? Or is it a mistake?

Comment: Are you speaking of a variant cover for AvX #1?

Comment: @chcuk no...let me clear up the question.

Comment: Smells like a mistake, but than again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the webs are stabilizers for Spider-Man and Daredevil, like the poles mostly everyone else is holding.

[image: Panel from comic]

Comment: Interesting. It looks like that everyone who can't fly or isn't a Thing/Hulk needs some kind of stabilizer. Most have the poles, but Spidey naturally has a web. And it does look like DD is holding webbing too. Does DD need stabilizing? And who's that behind and between DD and Spidey -- is that T'Challa? And what's stabilizing him?

Comment: It also looks like it could be a mistake, now that I see it. Spidey's left hand might have been intended to hold that webbing. It just ended up getting drawn in the wrong nearby hand, an easy enough mistake. Especially since DD probably wouldn't need any stabilizing.

Comment: @MarkBeadles that is the Black Panther(T'Challa) between the two of them but could have just as easily been a drawing mistake

Answer (score -1):

I can't find a copy of the panel that you reference (don't have the book myself), however I suspect you're not seeing webbing, but rather his cane extended to use the ~30ft. cabling.

From [Marvel.com Daredevil page](http://marvel.com/universe/Daredevil_(Matthew_Murdock)):

> Daredevil carries a billy club, disguised as a cane in civilian garb. It is a versatile, multi-purpose weapon, stronger than any fist. **It contains thirty feet of aircraft control cable, which is connected to a case-hardened steel grapnel. Internal mechanisms allow the cable to be neatly wound and unwound, while a powerful spring launches the grapnel.** Daredevil usually carries two fighting batons.

AvX promo cover*:
[image]

*Image not mine. Discovered at and represented from http://www.newsarama.com/comics/avengers-vs-xmen-teasers-120109.html

Comment: It's not that, at least I don't think. This is a preview of [AvX #2](http://supernovo.net/wp-content/gallery/avx-2/avx-2-preview-06.jpg) see the webbing by dare devil? It's not as clear as in issue one but he has got some sort of webbing.

Comment: @Pureferret Hrm - yeah, I think I see what you're talking about there, though you're right in that it's not clear. Apparently he only had the 1 panel appearance in AvX #1 according to [themanwithoutfear.com](http://www.manwithoutfear.com/ddNEWS.shtml) ... he also recently appeared in Avenging Spider-Man #6 as part of the Omega Effect (same release date). Not sure if there's continuity, but maybe this webbing, if actually attached to DD, came from that? I'm all speculation and may delete this answer as it appears inaccurate.

Comment: It's not clear that that's webbing - and it's closer to Ben Grimm anyway. Hmmm...webslinging Thing? ;)

Comment: @Josh leave it for now, we'll see if I can get a better picture.

Comment: @MarkBeadles It's much clearer in AvX #1